# Printing a list of graph leaves in PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog, nodes, graph-theory

I need to print a list of leaves in directed graph in Prolog.

I'm a Prolog beginner, this is one of my school tasks...

i.e. my graph is:

```
oh(0,1).
oh(0,2).
oh(2,3).
oh(2,4).
oh(3,4).
oh(4,5).
oh(3,6).
oh(4,8).
```

I think I've made a rule for finding leaves and putting them to the list.  (only not sure about that fail at the end.)

```
addtolist([Node], List, [Node|List]):-
   oh(_, Node),
    not(oh(Node, _)),
    fail.
```

but I don't know how to show this list. 
Actually I want to write in console something like `?- show.` and I want to get something like `1,5,6,8`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a good idea in asking for something which doesn't link to anything else; I would codify that as its own predicate like so:

```
leaf_node(Node) :- 
  oh(_, Node),
  \+ oh(Node, _).
```

I recommend you use `\+/1` instead of `not/1` because it is ISO. And you can see this works still:

```
?- leaf_node(Node).
Node = 1 ;
Node = 5 ;
Node = 6 ;
Node = 8.
```

Now, there are two ways to go when it comes to printing it out. A failure-driven loop seems to be what you're aiming for, and it is fairly simple, which would be like this:

```
show_leaves :-
  leaf_node(Node),
  write(Node), nl,
  fail.
show_leaves :- true.
```

This works like so:

```
?- show_leaves.
1
5
6
8
true.
```

A fancier version of the same thing would be to use `forall/2`, which looks like this:

```
?- forall(leaf_node(Node), (write(Node), nl)).
1
5
6
8
true.
```

However, failure-driven looping as a practice is considered kind of grody by modern Prolog standards because it doesn't generalize well (in a funny way, a failure-driven loop wants to be the "leaf code" in the system and can complicate interpreting failures). Because you want to acquire multiple solutions you will need to use a second-order predicate such as `bagof/3` or `setof/3`, which is going to look like this:

```
?- bagof(Node, leaf_node(Node), LeafNodes).
LeafNodes = [1, 5, 6, 8].
```

This is probably what most of us would do. In fact you can squeeze the whole `leaf_node/2` definition in there if you want, but you'll need to use an existential quantification to tell `bagof` that you don't care about the nodes that your leaf node is or is not connected to:

```
?- bagof(Node, A^B^(oh(A, Node), \+oh(Node, B)), LeafNodes).
LeafNodes = [1, 5, 6, 8].
```

I find the quantification thing a bit hard to wrap my head around.

Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: @tereza, please accept his answers as well if you do.